# What kind of diagram is this?

Tags: data-flow-diagram

I was given an API document that contained this diagram.  And I was amazed at how cleanly it presents the flow of data between multiple endpoints by putting the end points in vertical silos. Data event flow moves from top to bottom, going back and forth across the diagram.

Is there a name for this kind of diagram in particular -- something more specific than just "Data flow diagram"? And especially, how can I easily make one with this kind of arrangement? I don't know what to search for to find something this specific.

I've redacted the information that was originally shown.

[image: Flow Diagram]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_diagram

Comment: Thank you sir!!  That is everything I needed. :)

Comment: Aka _fence diagram_.

Comment: A heavily redacted diagram.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per commentor's response above:

It is a [Sequence Diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_diagram)

Now that I know that, searching google for "Sequence Diagram" shows a lot of examples of exactly the same setup.

**Update** March 29, 2020

I was informed that another diagram similar to this is the ["swimlane" diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swim_lane). Folks interested in a sequence diagram may also be interested in a swimlane diagram.

Answer (score 1):

This diagram is sequence diagram.

A sequence diagram shows object interactions arranged in time sequence. It depicts the objects and classes involved in the scenario and the sequence of messages exchanged between the objects needed to carry out the functionality of the scenario.

The reason the sequence diagram is so useful is because it shows the interaction logic between the objects in the system in the time order that the interactions take place.

A sequence diagram is a type of interaction diagram because it describes how—and in what order—a group of objects works together. These diagrams are used by software developers and business professionals to understand requirements for a new system or to document an existing process.

References:

https://g.co/kgs/2gLifw

https://visual-paradigm.com/guide/uml-unified-modeling-language/what-is-sequence-diagram/